# VHDL Shift Register Program different results when using signals and variables

Tags: vhdl

So I've been using VHDL to make a register, where it loads in the input X if LOAD is '1' , and outputs the data in serial fashion , basically a parallel in serial out register. The input X is a 4 bit ( 3 downto 0 ) input , what I want to make the program do is constantly output 0 when the register has successfully output all the btis in the input.

It works when "count" is defined as a signal , however , when count is defined as a variable , the output is a constant 0 , regardless of whether load is '1' or not. My code is as shown:

```
entity qn14 is
  Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
         reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
         LOAD : in  STD_LOGIC;
         X : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
         output : out  STD_LOGIC);
end qn14;

architecture qn14_beh of qn14 is
  type states is ( IDLE , SHIFT );
  signal state : states;
  signal count: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
begin

  process(clk , reset)
    variable temp: STD_LOGIC;
    variable data: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
  begin
    if reset = '1' then
      state <= IDLE;
      count <= "00";
      output <= '0';
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
      case state is
        when IDLE =>
          if LOAD = '1' then
            data := X;
            output <= '0';
            state <= SHIFT;
          elsif LOAD = '0' then
            output <= '0'; 
          end if;

        when SHIFT =>
          if LOAD ='1' then
            output <= '0';
          elsif LOAD = '0' then
            output <= data( conv_integer(count) );
            count <= count + 1;
            if (count >= 3) then
              state <= IDLE ;
            end if;
          end if;
      end case;
    end if;
  end process;

end qn14_beh;
```

Hoping to seek clarification on this.

Thank you.

Comment: ***It works when "count" is defined as a signal , however , when count is defined as a variable , the output is a constant 0 , regardless of whether load is '1' or not.***  Yes, but what is your question? You don't show the version with `count` as a variable and your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Assignment to a variable is immediate, the new value can be evaluated in an expression immediately. Signal value assigned are scheduled, a projected output waveform and the value available in a future simulation cycle.

Answer (score 0):

This may not fully answer your question, but I will cover several issues that I see.

The `elsif LOAD = '0' then` could just be `else` unless you're trying to cover the other states (X,U...) but you would still want an `else` to cover those.

`count = 3` is clearer than `count >= 3`. `count` is a 2-bit vector, so it can never be greater than 3.

Although you output `0` when `LOAD` is asserted while in the `SHIFT` state, you don't actually load a new value. Did you intend to?

Changing count to a variable without changing the position of the assignments will cause your first `X` -> `output` sequence to abort a cycle early (you increment `count` before you test it against 3). It will cause subsequent `X` -> `output` sequences to go "`X(3)`, `X(0)`, `X(1)`, `X(2)`"

The variable `temp` is never used. The variable `data` would work just as well as a signal. You do not need the properties of variables for this use. This also brings up the question of why you tried `count` as variable; unless you need the instant assignments of variables, it is typically better to use a signal because signals are easier to view in (most) simulators and harder to make mistakes with. I hope that you aren't trying to end up with `count` as a variable, but just have an academic curiosity why it doesn't work.

Have you looked at this in a simulator? Are you changing states properly? Are all the bits of all your inputs strongly driven to a defined value (`'1'` or `'0'`)?

I don't see anything that would cause the failure you described merely from changing `count` to a variable from a signal, but the change would cause the undesired behavior described above. My best guess is that your symptom arises from an issue with how you drive your inputs.